# Youtube buffering painfully slow lately

Tags: performance, download, youtube, buffer

Usually I can easily watch 1080p no problem, as I should.
Now, it's so slow I have to wait a couple of minutes for it to buffer only to be interrupted again 5 minutes in to the video and having to wait again.

Here's my speedtest [result](http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/4897844167)

As you can see my download speed is plenty fast.
I don't know why the upload is so slow right now(it's usually around 7-10Mbps), but that shouldn't affect the buffering much, right?
The ping is that high because I'm using a VPN. (connecting to a German server from Finland)

Any idea why youtube would be buffering so slow?
I suppose the VPN could be causing some sort of a problem, but I've been using it for quite some time now and youtube has been buffering just fine previously.

Comment: This is *way* off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Wait what... lol. I honestly though I was in Super user. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload should have very little effect on the streaming - you only upload when you request more of the video and it's unlikely that that is happening constantly (connections stay open a while).

Speed tests don't tell you much - it's a theoretical speed against a good server with a good network in between. ISPs may also hike the result of the speed test by prioritising traffic to the speed test server; cheeky.

In reality streaming from YouTube is more complex.

**I blame your ISP for bottle-necking the traffic ("traffic shaping") - it helps to make regular page loading (social media, etc) faster for everyone else. Look up net neutrality if you have time.**

Obviously I don't have evidence for this; it's just the most logical explanation. Unfortunately nobody at your ISP will give you a good answer.

I'd also not stream over a VPN anyway; that is a bottle neck in itself skipping optimisation the network/server could do before reaching your client directly.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It seems fine right now, which does support your theory about the ISP since it's almost 2am here right now. Traffic must be much less at this hour, freeing bandwidth for me. Since the problem does come and go, I don't think there's really anything wrong on my end, or it would persist more(?) That said, I suppose I could disable my VPN, but it is a paid "quality service" and has served me well, so I don't think it's that much of a bottleneck. Anyways, thanks again.